# Copying Core Data Model to a new Project, incomprehensible archive

Tags: ios, core-data

I am taking an existing App I have in the Apple App Store and want to start over from scratch, but don't want the existing user to lose their data stored in a core data model.

I started a new project using core data.  Copied over the core data model from the old project into the new project.  Removed the boilerplate core data model created by the new project.  Copied over the managed object classes from the old project.  Made the necessary changes in the AppDelegate to match the core data model I copied.  When I first run in the simulator it launches fine.  I then copy live data from my iPad into the simulator document directory and try to run again.  That's when I get the error "[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive"  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or step I missed to do this.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like WAL is biting you.  When you do the copy over, make sure you remove up to three files in the documents directory that have the same file name as your sqlite file (one will be your sqlite file).  Then copy over the new one.

WAL has journal files that it will attempt to use when you launch the second time and they will be incompatible with the store you copied over.

### Update

If you are getting the error at a `NSFetchedResultsController` call AND you have proper error logging in the creation of the Core Data stack then this is not an issue with the SQLite file itself but something wrong with the data internal to it.

Do you have any binary objects or transformable objects?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but after the second launch - when it crashes, I remove both the WAL and SHM files leaving only the sqlite database intact. The result is the same, "incomprehensible archive" and the two files are back there also (after I ran it)

Comment: They would come back as it opens the SQLite file and creates new journal files.  What is the code that reports the error?  What is the full error? Please edit the question so I can try and see what is going on.

Comment: The full error is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x30, 0x2e, 0x39, 0x31, 0x36, 0x39, 0x36, 0x38)'`  I've yet to do much with the code, the error is triggered by an NSLog that is trying to display the `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]`

Comment: **Re: Update**  Yes I have some of both binary and transformable objects in the core data model.

Comment: One of those is causing your issue.  Seems like the transformation of one of the binary properties is failing.

Comment: I agree.  To test I switch to an entity in the same core data model that did not contain any transient properties and the table loaded fine.  In the entity that is crashing I have three transient properties that are NSString.  I can't figure out why they would be causing the error though.